# Trying to download and verify .deb files

Tags: downloads, deb, gnupg

I am trying to download and verify all .deb files on http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/acct/

I do not want to use apt because I believe that would limit me to .deb files for my architecture and also would limit me in which versions are supported

I am thinking to use wget or curl for downloading so that I am not limited by what is available on my system (architecture, versions, ect).

As for verification, I see some .dsc files, but I believe those are only for verifying source code.

How can I verify the downloaded .deb files? I would prefer to verify using a signature, not just checking the sha256sum. However, if there is not way to verify signatures, checking the hash will do.

Update: I have tried dpkg --add-architecture  and ran apt-get update, but I am still not able to use apt to download non-compatible software.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Start with the canonical documentation on the topic: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/deb-pack-sign.en.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You should use the packages provided by apt, which are configured for that version of Ubuntu unless you absolutely require something else. Otherwise you may end up in a [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) . I did not get what you mean by "so that I am not limited by what is available on my system". What do you want to achieve? You cannot install the .deb files of different architectures in a single computer (without virtualization).

Comment: What was wrong with `apt-get download acct acct:i386` from [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=acct)? What is your target Ubuntu version? Why do you invent new package management procedure? Why do you need verification of packages from trusted source?

Comment: The OP seems to have clearly stated what they want to do: Download debs from the Ubuntu Repositories and verify the signatures and/or hashes. This is a permitted activity as long as it does not have onerous effects upon the mirrors. Our fellow volunteers poking about in unexpected ways like this is one way we discover bugs and security flaws, make our systems more robust...and recruit new apt developers.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, I am not trying to actually use these different packages or install them, I just want to download them and verify the downloads

Comment: @N0rbert I tried the command you suggested and my Ubuntu system was unable to locate that package. I can only seem to download that package using wget / curl. I do not have a target version to install these packages on. I just want to download, verify and look at the various packages. I want to verify the download using signatures because eventually this verification process to be  automated.

Comment: Then you have to check your repositories and Ubuntu version. Please add output of the following commands: `grep -r "^deb\ " /etc/apt/ --include=*.list`, `sudo apt-get update`, `apt-cache policy acct`. If long - use pastebin.

Comment: @N0rbert, I was able to confirm that I have the ubuntu main repository after using that first command. After the last command, I was able to see that acct version 6.6.4-1 is the only version available to me. Unless there is a way to add-apt repository to allow all versions and architectures for download, I think we are moving in the wrong direction. I am interested in downloading a package from the ubuntu main server and then verifying it. How can I verify a downloaded .deb file?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is simpler way, but below is the possible lowest-level way.

So we know the package name, the `acct`, it is located in [*main* pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=acct). I'll use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (*focal*) in below example.

Then we need to get `Packages` file from the mirror:

```
cd /tmp
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
```

and get SHA256 sum from it for needed package:

```
xzcat Packages.xz | grep acct.*deb -A4 | grep SHA256 | awk '{print $2}' | tee acct.sha256
```

Then we can get the correct file name by consulting with https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/acct to compare the sum:

```
cd /tmp
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/acct/acct_6.6.4-2_amd64.deb
# or construct it
wget -c "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/$(xzcat Packages.xz | grep acct.*deb | awk '{print $2}')"

sha256sum acct_6.6.4-2_amd64.deb
```

or with more automated variant:

```
comm <(sha256sum acct_6.6.4-2_amd64.deb | awk '{print $1}') <(cat acct.sha256) && echo OK || echo NOK
```

---

Notes:

1. for other CPU architectures (*armhf*, *arm64*, *s390x* and *ppc64el*) use file structure of http://ports.ubuntu.com with above approach.
2. please note that you can get "dependency hell" problem with current approach. So for massive deb-packages download with dependencies for known Debian-based distro version you can use my special Docker-based script located at https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download (see its README.md for details).

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how this works for acct_6.6.4-2? I tried your method, and it only worked for the version in the example.

Comment: Updated answer for 20.04. See its [history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1328254/timeline#history_581c78b2-6f7d-4882-a286-a6ba4c4f0372) for details.

Comment: @Norbert, I meant other versions of the library, not ubuntu versions